# User defined Characters as bullets in CSS lists

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS/HTML, if I want to set bullets to user defined chars like #, |, >..etc

How can I do that in CSS is any property available or any solution for such context

```
 <ul>
    <li></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried, for instance, to paste your question's title in Google and try any of the first 10 results?

Comment: Css is vast, since 4 days I was learning..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pseudo-element `:before` and define the content you want e.g.:

```css
ul {
   list-style: none;
}

ul li:before {
   content: "#";
   padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
    <li>test</li>
 </ul>
```

**Ref**

[:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)